# How to append rows in a python list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, append

I want to append a row in a python list.

Below is what I am trying,

```
# Create an empty array
arr=[]
values1 = [32, 748, 125, 458, 987, 361]
arr = np.append(arr, values1)
print arr
```

> [  32.  748.  125.  458.  987.  361.]

I want to append second row in the list, so that I will get an array like

> [ [32.  748.  125.  458.  987.  361.], [42.  344.  145.  448.  187. 
>   304.]]

I am getting error when I try to add second row

```
values2 = [42, 344, 145, 448, 187, 304]    
arr = np.append(arr, values2)
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just append directly to your original list:

```
# Create an empty list
my_list = []
values1 = [32, 748, 125, 458, 987, 361]
my_list.append(values1)
print(my_list)

values2 = [42, 344, 145, 448, 187, 304]    
my_list.append(values2)
print(my_list)
```

And this will be your output:

```
[[32, 748, 125, 458, 987, 361]]
[[32, 748, 125, 458, 987, 361], [42, 344, 145, 448, 187, 304]]
```

Hope that helps!